# Defining constant as function result in header = bad idea?

Tags: c++

In a widely used include file in one of our projects we have these convenience constants:

```
const double kPi        = asin(1.0) * 2.0;
const double kPiHalf    = asin(1.0);
const double kDeg2Rad = asin(1.0) / 90.0;
const double kRad2Deg = 90.0 / asin(1.0);
```

Is it a bad idea to use function results to calculate (precise) constants once at runtime?

Some recent crash dumps (on OS X) we've received look dodgy - they've got a stack frame with the address of the `const double kRad2Deg` line at a deep level though the crash occurs somewhere in the app way up the stack trace. Weird.

Does calling the math functions very early during the startup phase possibly screw up things?

I know we could just replace the function calls with constants but I'd like to understand the problem (if there is any) in general.

Comment: Why not use `M_PI` and `M_PI_2` from `<cmath>`?

Comment: Ah! `<cmath>`! `M_PI`!! Genius! See how old this code is... ;-) Thanks, mate!!

Comment: @larsmans Those aren't standard unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkB: no, but they're quite uniquitous. I don't understand why they still haven't been added to the standard.

Comment: why don't use [boost/math/constants/](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/constants/constants.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, use `<cmath>`.

Long answer: calling functions in static initialisers is a thorny problem because a function might itself depend on statically-initialised data and the order of initialisation is not defined, so *in general*, this is bad practice.

foo.cpp

```
namespace {std :: vector <int> data;}
int foo (int i) {
    data .push_back (i);
    return data .size ();
}
```

bar.cpp

```
int f = foo (123);
```

This is dangerous because `data` may not have been constructed. The safe version of foo.cpp would be

```
namespace {
    std :: vector <int> & data () {
        static std :: vector <int> d;
        return d;
    }
}
int foo (int i) {
    data () .push_back (i);
    return data () .size ();
}
```

If you can't guarantee that all the functions involved follow this pattern, you're not safe.

On the other hand, static built-in types have their values loaded into memory before ANYTHING happens, so they're ok.

foo.cpp

```
const double pi = M_PI;
```

bar.cpp

```
int main () {
    double foo = pi;
}
```

This is fine.

Still, use `<cmath>`, its values are required by the standard to be as accurate as can possibly be represented. Performing `90.0/asin(1.0)` is only compounding inaccuracies.

Comment: Well, sure - but would a standard C library call potentially suffer from this?

Comment: C library functions, no, because all their static data should be of built-in type. They have no constructors (although initializer functions are possible with compiler extensions).

Comment: Right. So it's not evident whether our constant-function-call construct could cause a crash.. ah, well - switching to `<cmath>` anyway and see what happens!

Answer (score 2):

This actually isn't necessarily a bad idea ... some compilers like gcc will take functions like trig functions, square-roots, etc., and using higher-end math libraries like GMP and MPFR, etc., pre-calculate the results if the value being passed to the function is a constant expression, and the result is being passed to a constant expression.  By using a library like GMP for the results, rather than computing the results at runtime using the standard platform-dependent libc implementations, you can get more accurate results as the basis for your constant numbers, as well as consistent results across platforms, since libraries like GMP/MPRF are designed to account for floating point rounding errors, etc. and result in the same value across multiple platforms.

As pointed out though, problems can occur if you are dependent on these values being initialized before the initialization of other static objects.  According to the C++11 spec, section 3.6.2 though, constant initialization takes place before dynamic initialization ... so as long as your expressions qualify for constant initialization, and do not somehow create a circular dependency, then you should be okay with initialization ordering.  Any other static objects not constant initialized will be dynamically initialized, and if they are dependent on your constants, those values will already be initialized when dynamic initialization takes place.

Comment: Exactly, that was the idea behind using function calls rather than predefined constants.

Comment: C isn't supposed to be binary-portable across platforms. If you want another target platform, you should be recompiling. If that platform has a different numerical precision, the values in `<cmath>` will be different. There is no *need* for this, and even when it's safe for one example, it's a bad habit in general.

Comment: I agree with your general-use scenario, but using the constants defined in `<cmath>` will only get you so far. For instance, square-root functions, logarithms, etc. are not all fixed constants like Pi, the square-root of 2, the value of "e", etc.  So you can take advantage of the fact some compilers will substitute constant math expressions with more accurate results than the platform built-in implementations of those same functions that would be calculated at run-time.